# Is it possible that the number of parameters is different even though the neural network model has the same structure?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm trying to make 2 Fully-Connected DNN models with the same structure to copy the weights of one to another later.

Since they have the same structure, I don't have to make different codes so I used the same code to make 2 DNN objects.

However, the results were so strange because the number of parameters was different although I use the same code and the same hyperparameters!

For example, I set the same number of neurons as fellows:
Input Layer: 3
1st Hidden Layer: 256
2nd Hidden Layer: 256
Output Layer: 2

However, the summaries of the two models generated were as follows:

####### Model 1 #####
Model: "dnn"

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0
**dense (Dense)                multiple                  1024**
dense_1 (Dense)              multiple                  65792
dense_2 (Dense)              multiple                  514

Total params: 67,330
Trainable params: 67,330
Non-trainable params: 0

---

####### Model 2 #####
Model: "dnn_1"

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 3)]               0
**dense_3 (Dense)              multiple                  768**
dense_4 (Dense)              multiple                  65792
dense_5 (Dense)              multiple                  514

Total params: 67,074
Trainable params: 67,074
Non-trainable params: 0

---

I've checked my code several times, but I just used the same hyperparameters for 2 DNN objects.

How can *dense* and *dense_3* have different numbers of parameters?

Can you give me some advice on this?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the layer names, layer names of model 2 are greater than model 1, for example input layer of model 1 is input_1 whereas that of model 2 is input_2, it clearly indicates that for model 2 tensorflow added nodes in the same graph which is created for model 1.

You need to clear the session before building model 2, Clearing the session removes all the nodes left over from previous models.

Use below code before building the model 2, use the import statement at top of the file.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()
```